# Closed form of recurrence relation $a_{n}=a_{n-1}(a_{n-2}^{2}-a_{0})-a_{1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

Given the following sequence:

> $$\begin{cases}a_{0}=2\\a_{1}=\frac{5}{2}\\a_{n}=a_{n-1}(a_{n-2}^{2}-a_{0})-a_{1}\end{cases}$$

Prove that

$$a_{n}=2^{\frac{2^{n}-(-1)^{n}}{3}}+2^{\frac{(-1)^{n}-2^{n}}{3}}$$

For all natural numbers $n$.

---

**My try: (using induction)**

Let $b_{n}=\frac{2^{n}-(-1)^{n}}{3}$

For $n=0$: correct $\checkmark$

Now for $n+1$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{n+1} &= a_{n}(a_{n-1}^{2}-a_{0})-a_{1})=(2^{b_{n}}+2^{-b_{n}})(2^{2b_{n}}+2^{-2b_{n}}+2) \\
&=2^{3b_{n}}+2^{-3b_{n}}+2^{b_{n}}+2^{-b_{n}}+2^{b_{n}+1}+2^{-b_{n}+1}
\end{aligned}
$$

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Check formula for $n=3$. It seems incorrect, cause $a_{n} = \frac{5}{2}$, using recurent sequence and $a_n = 8\frac{1}{8}$ using formula

Answer (score 3):

You want to proof that $a_n = f(n)$ for any $n\inℕ$ with
$$ f(n) := 2^{\frac{2^{n}-(-1)^{n}}{3}}+2^{\frac{(-1)^{n}-2^{n}}{3}}.$$

**Check of two (!) initial conditions:**

- $f(0) = 2 = a_0 \checkmark$
- $f(1) = \frac52 = a_1 \checkmark$

**Inductive step:**
$$\begin{aligned}
a_{n+1} &= a_n (a_{n-1}^2 - a_0) - a_1\\
&= f(n) (f(n-1)^2 - f(0)) - f(1)\\
&= (2^{b_n} + 2^{-b_n}) \cdot ((2^{b_{n-1}} + 2^{-b_{n-1}})^2 - 2) - \frac52\\
&= (2^{b_n} + 2^{-b_n}) \cdot (2^{2b_{n-1}} + 2^{-2b_{n-1}}) - \frac52 \\
&= 2^{b_n+2b_{n-1}} + 2^{b_n-2b_{n-1}} + 2^{-b_n+2b_{n-1}} +  2^{-b_n-2b_{n-1}} - \frac52 \end{aligned}$$
Simple computations show that:
$$\begin{aligned}
b_n+2b_{n-1} &= \frac13(2^{n+1} + (-1)^n) = b_{n+1}\\
b_n-2b_{n-1} &= (-1)^{n+1}.
\end{aligned}$$

Thus
$$a_{n+1} = f(n+1) + 2^{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{(-1)^n} - \frac52$$

With the equality (for $n\in\mathbb N$)
$$2^{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{(-1)^n} = \frac52$$
we can finish the proof:
$$a_{n+1} = f(n+1).$$

Comment: Hi , thanks! How is this : With the equality $2^{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{(-1)^n} = \frac52$ can you explain I think $2^{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{(-1)^n} ≠ \frac52$

Comment: For even $n$ you have $2^{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{(-1)^n} = 2^{-1} + 2^1 = \frac52$ and for odd $n$ you have $2^{(-1)^{n+1}} + 2^{(-1)^n} = 2^1 + 2^{-1} = \frac52$.

Comment: thanks! Sir 

Comment: you could accept my answer when you think it is solves your problem